# How to return select values when join with ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm using ecto 2.2.6.

I'm trying left join by ecto.

At first, I used List to return select values with single table. (1)

Next I used Map to return select values because of table join. (2)

```
Repo.all(from m in "members",
    left_join: g in "groups",
           on: g.id == m.group_id,
        where: g.id == ^group_id
# select: [:id, :group_id, :name, :group_name] #(1)
# select: {m.id, m.group_id, m.name, g.group_name} #(2)
)
```

I would like to make select box in HTML.
It does not work, because of no key when I use Map.

```
<%= select f, :group_id, Enum.map(@groups, &{&1.group_name, &1.group_id}) %>
```

How should I get select and use select values?
I would like to know how to return select value with ecto and recive in select box in general.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually your second approach will produce a list of tuples when the query is executed. We can't use that dot syntax to fetch elements of a tuple. Map literals in elixir are denoted, as far as I know, by `%{}`. So changing your `select` to a map may help. Something like this:

```
Repo.all(from m in "members",
    left_join: g in "groups",
           on: g.id == m.group_id,
        where: g.id == ^group_id
    select: %{
      id: m.id,
      group_id: m.group_id,
      name: m.name,
      group_name: g.group_name
    }
)
```

If you are not using the extra data you could just do

```
Repo.all(from m in "members",
    left_join: g in "groups",
           on: g.id == m.group_id,
        where: g.id == ^group_id
    select: %{
      group_id: m.group_id,
      group_name: g.group_name
    }
)
```

Or you may just select a tuple with the information you need and pass the query result directly to the `select` tag

```
Repo.all(from m in "members",
    left_join: g in "groups",
           on: g.id == m.group_id,
        where: g.id == ^group_id
    select: {m.group_id, g.group_name}
)

# And avoid the Enum.map in the select tag
<%= select f, :group_id, @groups %>
```

The phoenix documentation for this may interest you: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#select/4.

Hope it helps. =)

Comment: I did not recognize map %{} or tuple {} in case of #2. Thank you. very helpful.